# How to stop Gson converting numbers into strings while deserializing?

Tags: java, gson

I am converting an arbitrary JSON dictionary (object) into a Java map with Gson. The dictionary is arbitrary so it may contain both number and string values.

The source code below leads to JSON numbers being parsed into strings (!) in float exponental form (!!) like "1.23456789E8".

How to teach Gson to convert JSON numbers into Java numbers, but not into Java strings?

```
// a demo of the unwanted behaviour
String json = "{\"int\": 123456789}";
Map map = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
assert map.get("int").equals("1.23456789E8");
```

Java 1.6, Gson 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Gson Documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

> When you call toJson(obj), Gson calls obj.getClass() to get information on the fields to serialize. Similarly, you can typically pass MyClass.class object in the fromJson(json, MyClass.class) method. This works fine if the object is a non-generic type. However, if the object is of a generic type, then the Generic type information is lost because of Java Type Erasure

If your Map (or some other collection) has a generic type , like `Map<String,Integer>`, then you cannot directly mention the type into `fromJson()` .

You will have to do a workaround, since supplying Map.class in the type directly, loses the `<String,Integer>` type generic. This will make it work:-

```
java.lang.reflect.Type t = new TypeToken<Map<String,Integer>>() {}.getType();
Map<String,Integer> map1= (Map<String,Integer>) new Gson().fromJson(json, t);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there are mixed values in the input dictionary. I've updated the question.

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean by mixed values ?

Comment: `{"int": 123, "string": "xxx"}`. So it won't fit into `Map<String,Integer>`.

Comment: I tried `Map<String,String>` and the exponents has gone! This is a win already.

Comment: Thats great, you can always convert the json into Map of a specific  generic type, if you have mixed input you can write custom parser that reads the input type key, and then adds the values into the corresponding Map.